# what is the difference between standalone toolbar and toolbar as action bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, material-design

I am little bit confuse about  **standalone toolbar** & **toolbar as actionbar**.
Standalone toolbar can do the work of toolbar as actionbar then what is the need of toolbar as actionbar ?

Answer (score 0):

take a peek at the [documentation for android toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar) and notice that toolbar is portable and generic.

> A Toolbar is a generalization of action bars for use within application layouts. While an action bar is traditionally part of an Activity's opaque window decor controlled by the framework, a Toolbar may be placed at any arbitrary level of nesting within a view hierarchy.